# I want to do web scraping of this url ->" https://www.youtube.com/@PW-Foundation/videos"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I used BeautifulSoup and request libraries but I am getting confused on how to use `find_all()` to extract url, thumbnail, title, number of views and time of posting of first five videos of the given URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://www.youtube.com/@PW-Foundation/videos"
content=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(content.text,'html.parser')
soup.find_all('div', {"class":"yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail"})

#I tried this but it returns me an empty list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube wants you to accepts cookies before letting you access the page, and automatically **redirects** you to another page, therefore the HTML you are looking for isn't collected. Since it is a redirection it is not 'behind' the prompt. You can check for yourself by printing the first soup you get.

You could use a bot to 'click' on the accept button, for example with [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

PS: after that make sure to check if what you are looking for really exists (I didn't find it)